# Why is my python code giving wrong answers for only some inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, frequency

I am new to python and I was trying to write a program that gives the frequency of each letters in a string from a specific point. Now my code is giving correct output for some inputs like if I give the input "hheelloo", I get the correct output, but if the input is "hheelllloooo", the frequency of h,e and l is printed correct, but the frequency of 'o' comes out as 7 if the starting point is index 0. Can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong.

Write a Python program that counts the occurrence of Character in a String (Do
not use built in count function.
Modify the above program so that it starts counting
from Specified Location.

```
str = list(map(str, input("Enter the string : ")))
count = 1
c = int(input("Enter the location from which the count needs to start : "))
for i in range(c, len(str)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(str)):
        if str[i] == str[j]:
            count += 1
            str[j] = 0
    if str[i] != 0:
        print(str[i], " appears ", count, " times")
        count = 1
```

Comment: Try adding a `print` statement inside your innermost `if`, like `print(f'str[{i}] was equal to str[{j}], so we will increment the count')`, and then test the code with the simpler input of `'xxx'`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: You really have two tasks, right? Figure out which characters are in the string (starting from the start point), and then figure out how many times each of those characters appears. Right? So, what if you try to solve those tasks separately? Can you find a simpler way to solve the problem?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes understood the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = list(map(str, input("Enter the string : ")))
count = 1
c = int(input("Enter the location from which the count needs to start : "))
for i in range(c, len(str)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(str)):
        if str[i] == str[j]:
            count += 1
            str[j] = 0
    if str[i] != 0:
        print(str[i], " appears ", count, " times")
    count = 1 // <----- This line should be outside the if block.
```

The error was because of indentation.
I have just properly indented the last line.

Thanks, if it works, kindly upvote.

Comment: thanks bro for the help, it solved the problem. stackoverflow is not letting me to upvote since i am new and need 15 reputations, but once i have them i will surely upvote you.

Comment: Okay Sagnik. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

`string` module can be useful and easy to calculate the frequency of letters, numbers and special characters in a string.

```
import string

a='aahdhdhhhh2236665111...//// '

for i in string.printable:
    z=0
    for j in a:
        if i==j:
            z+=1
    if z!=0:
        print(f'{i} occurs in the string a {z} times')
```

If you want to calculate the frequency of characters from a particular index value, you just have to modify the above code a little as follows:

```
import string

a='aahdhdhhhh2236665111...//// '
c = int(input("Enter the location from which the count needs to start : "))
for i in string.printable:
    z=0
    for j in a[c:]:
        if i==j:
            z+=1
    if z!=0:
        print(f'{i} occurs in the string a {z} times')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to `map` the `input` to `list` of `str` as `input()` always returns a `string` and `string` itself is a `list` of characters. Also make sure you don't use the built-ins as your variable names (As `str` used in your code). One of the simpler approach can be:

```
input_word = input("Enter the string : ")
c = int(input("Enter the location from which the count needs to start : "))
# Dict to maintain the count of letters
counts = {}
for i in range(c, len(input_word)):
    # Increment 1 to the letter count
    counts[input_word[i]] = counts.get(input_word[i], 0)+1
    
for letter, freq in counts.items():
    print (f'{letter} appears {freq} times')
```

Output:

```
Enter the string : hheelllloooo
Enter the location from which the count needs to start : 2
e appears 2 times
l appears 4 times
o appears 4 times
```